# MPI to generate first 20 numbers

Tags: c++, mpi

Here is code that I was trying to generate the first 20 numbers starting from 0 in an attempt to learn MPI.

My code is given below :

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0;
void test(int edge_count){
   while(i < edge_count){
    printf("Edge count %d\n",i);
    i++;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 int edge_count = 20;
  // int *p = &i;
  // Initialize the MPI environment. The two arguments to MPI Init are not
  // currently used by MPI implementations, but are there in case future
  // implementations might need the arguments.
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  // Get the number of processes
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // Get the rank of the process
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  // Get the name of the processor
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int name_len;
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

  // Print off a hello world message
  printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
         processor_name, world_rank, world_size);
  test(edge_count);
  printf("The value of i is %d \n",i);

  // Finalize the MPI environment. No more MPI calls can be made after this
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

My output is :

```
Hello world from processor ENG401651, rank 0 out of 2 processors
Edge count 0
Edge count 1
Edge count 2
Edge count 3
Edge count 4
Edge count 5
Edge count 6
Edge count 7
Edge count 8
Edge count 9
Edge count 10
Edge count 11
Edge count 12
Edge count 13
Edge count 14
Edge count 15
Edge count 16
Edge count 17
Edge count 18
Edge count 19
The value of i is 20 
Hello world from processor ENG401651, rank 1 out of 2 processors
Edge count 0
Edge count 1
Edge count 2
Edge count 3
Edge count 4
Edge count 5
Edge count 6
Edge count 7
Edge count 8
Edge count 9
Edge count 10
Edge count 11
Edge count 12
Edge count 13
Edge count 14
Edge count 15
Edge count 16
Edge count 17
Edge count 18
Edge count 19
The value of i is 20
```

The code that I used to run it is:

```
mpirun -np 2 execFile
```

I was expecting that both the processor would communicate and generate a number from 0 to 19 only once but it seems like each of the processor are generating their own set of numbers independently.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to MPI and couldnot figure out what is the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers only do what you tell them to. This is true not just of MPI but of any kind of programming.

Where in your script did you explicitly tell the processors to divide the work between them? The thing is, you didn't. And it won't happen by automagically.

The following modified version of your code shows how you can use `world_size` and `world_rank` to have each process independently calculate what share of the work it should perform.

To better demonstrate the gains of parallelism, I use thread sleeping to simulate the time that would otherwise be taken by work in an actual implementation.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void test(int start, int end){
  for(int i=start;i<end;i++){
    printf("Edge count %d\n",i);
    //Simulates complicated, time-consuming work
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 int edge_count = 20;
  // int *p = &i;
  // Initialize the MPI environment. The two arguments to MPI Init are not
  // currently used by MPI implementations, but are there in case future
  // implementations might need the arguments.
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  // Get the number of processes
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // Get the rank of the process
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

  // Get the name of the processor
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  int name_len;
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

  // Print off a hello world message
  printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
         processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

  const int interval   = edge_count/world_size;
  const int iter_start = world_rank*interval;
  const int iter_end   = (world_rank+1)*interval;

  test(iter_start, iter_end);

  // Finalize the MPI environment. No more MPI calls can be made after this
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. Suppose I run the code with only one processor and it takes n seconds to execute it. Now, I run the same program using two processor. It should take n/2 seconds, right? Why is not this happening? It seems to be taking more time for 2 processors to perform the same taks. Does that also need to be specified somewhere?

Comment: @user9700881: What you're seeing is the overhead of parallelism: the two processes need to coordinate before beginning their work and when their work ends. Since the example program you've posted does no actual work (the for loop with the print is _very_ fast), the costs of parallelism outweigh the benefits. [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) offers another way to understand this.

Comment: @user9700881: To better demonstrate this, I've added a `sleep_for` inside of your for loop. This simulates the computational workload that would be present in a program you were actually trying to parallelize. If you run the code with this workload present, you'll see that it behaves much more like what you expect.

Comment: I am surprised to see that it prints only the even numbers. But the logic seems to print every number from 0 to 19.

Comment: And yeah I saw that use of multiple processor definitely reduces the time when I tried it for generating very large number of 8 figures

Comment: but why does it produce even numbers only and not the odd numbers? This is something I donot understant.

Comment: The `gi` variable that I included may be causing the effect you're seeing. I've removed it. See if the updated code does more what you're expecting.

Comment: It seems like this kind of sharing work in MPI works only for even process. For example, if have have 3 process and have to generate numbers from 0 to 19, it would not work. Doesnot it become difficult to create a system that works for odd or even processes for this program?

Comment: @user9700881: Yes, designing parallel programs is tricky. And there is no good way around that. For `N` tasks on `P` processors you could use integer division to get `N/P` tasks per processor and then assign `N-(N/P)*P` additional tasks to the last processor. Or some other scheme.

Comment: Keep at it: you'll get there:-)